# How to convert a csv file to json file so that each csv column (Not row!!) will be a list in the json file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Assume we have a csv file that looks like this:

```
a    b    c
1    2    3
1    2    3
1    2    3
```

I would like the json file to look like this:

```
{
   "a": [1,1,1],
   "b": [2,2,2],
   "c": [3,3,3]
}
```

I tried using pandas dataframe like this:

```
def func(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    df = pd.read_csv (csvFilePath)
    df.to_json(jsonFilePath, indent=2)
```

But it didnt have the expected output.
All the other posts I found seem to solve this problem for rows and not for columns.
Can someone point out what am I doing wrong or show another way to do it?

Comment: `df.to_dict('list')` / `json.dumps(df.to_dict('list'))`?

Comment: Have you tested the solutions above?